# How to enable daytime service on ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-10.04

I have found the following info on my machine

```
user@ubuntu:/etc/xinetd.d$ cat daytime
# default: off
# description: An internal xinetd service which gets the current system time
# then prints it out in a format like this: "Wed Nov 13 22:30:27 EST 2002".
# This is the tcp version.
service daytime
{
    disable     = yes
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = daytime-stream
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    user        = root
    wait        = no
}                                                                               

# This is the udp version.
service daytime
{
    disable     = yes
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = daytime-dgram
    socket_type = dgram
    protocol    = udp
    user        = root
    wait        = yes
}
```

**Question:**

How to enable the daytime service?

// Update // I have problems to do the step2

> Step 1:
>
> sudo aptitude install xinetd
>
> Step 2:  Next you'll need to enable the daytime and echo services by
>   editing their config files in /etc/xinetd.d (you should only need to
>   change the disable option from yes to no)
>
> Step 3: sudo invoke-rc.d xinetd reload

Comment: I have tried to directly modify the file /etc/xinetd.d/daytime and change the disable yes to no. But I am not able to save it.

Comment: You need to invoke the editor with sudo as well, so that you have permission to save the file.  Also, you do understand *why* the daytime service is disabled right?

Comment: @andrewdski, No, I don't understand why it is disabled. May you explain a little for me?

Comment: One reason is that *time* and *daytime* have been useless ever since NTP was created.

Comment: It is disabled because it is vulnerable to denial of service attacks.  See for example: http://descriptions.netvigilance.com/tc/15039.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/xinetd.d/*` is only writable by root. You can copy it to your home directory (`cp /etc/xinetd.d/daytime ~`), edit that, and then copy it back with root permission (`sudo cp ~/daytime /etc/xinetd.d`). Or you can edit it in-situ with an editor you trust to run as root, a la `sudo someeditor /etc/xinetd.d/daytime`.

Comment: You can automate the first approach as `sudo -e /etc/xinetd.d/daytime `, which will invoke an editor as you, not root, on a copy.